# Use Visual Basic for applications to read data from an Excel Spreadsheet database

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know if it's possible to read data from an Excel spreadsheet used as database with Visual Basic for application (The IDE included in Microsoft Excel). I know it's possible with Visual Basic Studio but I don't know if it's possible using the Visual Basic IDE integrated in microsoft Excel.

Basically what I want to do is to create and authentification system this way (The spreadsheet will haw 3 columns : ID, Login and Password).

I will not be surprised if you tell me that using an Excel file as a databse is not the best practice but it is imposed to me and I must do it this way.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a database. You can either call it with MS Query or open your dataset (invisibly) for reading. MS Query has the downside of considering values invalid at times.

Comment: Actually I already know that I wan use an Excel file as a database. What I would like to know is if it is possible using the IDE Visual basic for applications wich is included in Microsoft office Excel.

Comment: Open Method (Visible:=False), then read the data then Close method. Yes, it is possible.